Error CS1929: MonoBehaviour does not contain a definition of `OfType<>()`
I'm pretty new to C#/Unity. I'm getting this error:

CS1929: MonoBehaviour does not contain a definition of .OfType<>().

If I understand right, Systeme.Linq not recognize this function. What have I done wrong in this code?
DataPersitenceManager.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;


public class DataPersistenceManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private List<IDataPersistence> findAllDataPersistenceObjects()
    {
        IEnumerable<IDataPersistence> dataPersistenceObjects = FindObjectOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<IDataPersistence>();
        return new List<IDataPersistence>(dataPersistenceObjects);
    }
}

IDataPersistence.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IDataPersistence
{
    void loadData(gameData data);
    void saveData(ref gameData data);
}

gameData.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class gameData
{
}


Debugging question generally require a minimal, complete, verifiable example  (MCVE) - as posted, we can't tell you much about this beyond documentation for a cs1929 error: create an extension method for the type or move the call to where the method exists. That assumes that this is the actual problem & not the result of some other error(s) in the code & we can't tell that without a MCVE.

Also note that the Game Dev SE focuses on game development. general programming questions that aren't specific to game development are off-topic here (but can be asked on Stack Overflow). I can't tell for sure if this question would be off-topic here (because this question is incomplete), but to me it looks more like a general programming problem than a game dev problem.

Do not edit a question to put "[Resolved]" in the title. Instead, post your solution where it says "Your Answer" below. After a delay, you'll be able to click the ✅ icon to mark that answer as "Accepted" — that's how we resolve threads here. Also remember to read tag descriptions when tagging your question. This question is about C# in Unity, so you should use the [tag:unity] and [tag:c#] tags, not the [tag:UnityScript] tag — Unity has not supported that JavaScript-like UnityScript language in nearly a decade.

I feel so stupid right now...... i'm on this for 2 day and just found what was wrong
Original code:
private List<IDataPersistence> FindAllDataPersistenceObjects()
{
    IEnumerable<IDataPersistence> dataPersistenceObjects = FindObjectOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<IDataPersistence>();
    return new List<IDataPersistence>(dataPersistenceObjects);
}

Good code:
private List<IDataPersistence> FindAllDataPersistenceObjects()
{
    IEnumerable<IDataPersistence> dataPersistenceObjects = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<IDataPersistence>();
    return new List<IDataPersistence>(dataPersistenceObjects);
}

So yeah if you have good eye (not like me) FindObjectsOfType<>() was missing a s at Object....
Sorry for posting and self-solutioning but was deseparate haha

Remember to always search for the text of your error before posting a new question. The answer was already available to you here.
